# How to open a form with an ID in a MS Access Database?

Tags: c#, ms-access

i made a new C# program. With this program I want to open the form with the ID (e.g. Customer ID) from my Access database. I open my database with the following line: "Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Test.accdb");"

But I don't have an idea how can I open the form with the customer ID. How can I transfer the ID from the commandline to the database to open the form with the ID? Could you please give me a tip for this?

Thank you,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Macro in your Access database. Call it (as an example)  `OpenCustomerForm`. This macro should contain only a command to execute a function defined in a VBA Module.

For example

```
RunCode CustomerFormByID()
```

Then in a VBA Module (the name of the module is not important) create a function named `CustomerFormByID`

```
Public Function CustomerFormByID()
    Call DoCmd.OpenForm("NameOfFormThatShowCustomers", _ 
                        acNormal, "", _ 
                        "ID=" & Command, acFormEdit)
End Function
```

This function will try to open a form named after the one that you use to show your customers. The important part here is the WHERE condition in which you put the primary key of your customers table (supposing its named ID) and the Command function that return what is passed on the command line after the /cmd switch

Now in C# you call everything with

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "Test.accdb";
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop";
psi.Arguments = "/x OpenCustomerForm /cmd " + customerID.ToString();
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can I open the form without the macro in the database?

Comment: The only way (AFAIK) to interact with access through the command line is passing the name of a macro (or use the predefined Autoexec macro), otherwise you need to investigate if there is any way to communicate with Access using Interop